# convert millisecond to Joda Date Time or for zone 0000

Tags: android, jodatime

please tell me how to convert milliseconds to joda Date time??

```
formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(00, 00));
```

even tried

```
String millisecond="14235453511"
DateTime.parse(millisecond);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The answer given by @Adam S is almost okay. However, I would prefer to specify the timezone explicitly. Without specifying it you get the constructed `DateTime`-instance in the system timezone. But you want the zone "0000" (UTC)? Then look for this alternative [constructor](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-):

```
String milliseconds = "14235453511";
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(Long.valueOf(milliseconds), DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(someDate); // 1970-06-14T18:17:33.511Z
```

Comment: i want the time in 0000 zone only, its giving me +5:30 's time

Comment: @vaibhav How do you conclude that my suggestion yields the timezone offset +5:30? I have tested my code, and you can see the output above: The new constructed instance of `DateTime` is on "Z" (=UTC =+00:00).

Comment: i want the millisecond to give me the zonal time !! It gives me the indian time

Comment: @vaibhav And my question still stands how you conclude it? The output is: "1970-06-14T18:17:33.511Z" That is not Indian time but UTC-time. Please try to show more code which makes you thinking that my suggestion produces Indian Time.

Comment: No it was my mistake !! It gives the utc time !! U were rite !!

Comment: No it was my mistake !! It gives the utc time !! U were rite !!

Comment: @vaibhav You are welcome. Seems to have been a small misunderstanding.

Answer (score 22):

There's [a constructor that takes milliseconds](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long)):

```
long milliseconds = 14235453511;
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use this

```html
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        formatter.setCalendar(calendar);
        String timeZone = "GMT+2:00";
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

        String time = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

        System.out.println(time);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: This post does not answer the question regarding Joda DateTime