# Creating DateTime from long

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am using the **jodatime** lib for handling dates and timestamps. I am currently having a problem with creating a datetime object from a long:

```
DateTime e = new DateTime(new Long("5"));
System.out.println(e.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss,SSS")));
```

This prints

> "01:00:00,005"

to the console. This is not what I expect, that would be

> "00:00:00,005"

Did anybody had already had that problem or can explain that to me?

Comment: where are these classes from?

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html

Comment: Whats your time zone? The long specifies the data time in UTC, you print it in your local time zone.

Comment: **don't** use a `DateTime` as a [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/class-use/Duration.html).

Comment: my timezone is Europe/Berlin. What would a better class for handling durations?

Comment: @chris000r: `joda.time.Duration`.

Comment: thanks, did not see that there is a class for durations. Thanks for that advice, i should have had a deeper look to the lib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert millisecond to Joda Date Time or for zone 0000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709897/convert-millisecond-to-joda-date-time-or-for-zone-0000)

Comment: If your code base is already using Joda-Time and you’re happy with it, you may (or may not) ignore this comment. If you’re ready to move on, Joda-Time is a largely fínished project, and they recommend migrating to `java.time`. So you may consider [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) for your duration. For how to format it, search, it has been answered a couple of times here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Rather than using time-of-day format, consider displaying your duration using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: [PnYnMnDTnHnMnS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are living in UTC+1 timezone?  Unix Time epoch is based on UTC, because you are on UTC+1 timezone and when you set the long to zero, it's 00:00:00  UTC+0 = 01:00:00 @ UTC+1

To get the result your want, you can create your datetime as following:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(5L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss,SSS")));
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Well, "a time zone that used an offset of UTC+1 at the instant in time 5 milliseconds after the Unix epoch".

Comment: @Brilly Tsang

DateTime e = new DateTime(5L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(e.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss,SSS")));

This prints: 12:00:00,005

Comment: Right, System.out.println(e.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("**HH**:‌​mm:ss,SSS")));

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 answer.

```
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMillis(5);
    String formattedDur = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%02d:%02d:%02d,%03d",
            dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart(), dur.toSecondsPart(), dur.toMillisPart());
    System.out.println(formattedDur);
```

This prints

> 00:00:00,005

I am typing this answer for anyone not using Joda-Time and for anyone ready to move on. Joda-Time is a largely finished project with no major enhancements foreseen. Those folks recommend migrating to `java.time`.

`java.time.Duration` doesn’t lend itself very well to formatting, but with the introduction of the `toXxxPart` methods in Java 9 it has become better.